# How do I generate cargo docs for all platforms?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The `cargo` command line tool allows me to generate documentation for my crate, but I have structures like:

```
#[cfg(target-platform("windows")]
mod winstuff {
     /// Explanation of Windows-specific tasks
}

#[cfg(target-platfrom("linux")]
mod linstuff {
    /// Explanation of Linux-specific tasks
}
```

When I run `cargo docs --no-deps`, only the platform-specific module I'm generating documentation for gets generated. How can I generate documentation for *all* platforms?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy solution to this; the official Rust documentation [doesn't even have the `std::os::windows` module documented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24658) because of this very issue. The thread on GitHub hints at `docs.rs` having a solution, but I couldn't find the details.

Comment: docs.rs has a platform selector in the upper right hand corner, for every crate's docs.

Comment: `doc.rs` is manually generating the docs for each platform using a build script. According to [the cargo issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/1998). There is no fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a known bug, there is no current fix](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/1998).